# Download functionality in Grid column of magento 2

Tags: database, uicomponent, magento-2.1.3

In magento-2 admin grid column I want to show download action in one column as I have all my other fields like full name, view, email, created_at in grid.

And after clicking on "download action " my attachment that  user upload from frontned form.

I have shown grid using UI Component, here is my code "quote_request_listing.xml" file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../Magento/Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

<massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listingquote_request_listing.quote_request_listing_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/post/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Posts</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected Posts?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                        <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing_columns_editor</item>
                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>

 <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
               <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing_columns</item>

    </argument>

    <dataSource name="quote_request_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magecoder\Quote\Ui\DataProvider\QuoteDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render" />
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>        
    </dataSource>

    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridAcions</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                        <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filters</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>

            <filterInput name="full_name">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">full_name</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Name</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterInput>

              <filterInput name="email">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">email</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterInput>

            <filterInput name="created_at">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">created_at</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterInput>
        </filters>
    </container>

    <columns name="quote_request_listing_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">

                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="quote/request/inlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing.quote_request_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="full_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magecoder\Quote\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">quote/request/view</item>
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: have you found the solution, please share code.